# SQL Server : update duplicates by condition

Tags: sql-server, performance, duplicates

I have a query that runs on a table with 22mil records. The query need to update the duplicated rows by a condition.

The query with group by clause is getting me the records that doesn't need update(the newly inserted records) and i need to update all the others and set `is_deleted = 1`

```
UPDATE [SGC].[VANZARI_PRODUSE]
SET [IS_DELETED] = 1
FROM [SGC].[VANZARI_PRODUSE] [VP] 
INNER JOIN [SGC].[VANZARI] [V] ON [VP].[ID_VANZARE] = [V].[ID_VANZARE] 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         MAX([VP].[ID_VP]) AS [MAX_IDVP],
         [VP].[NUME_PRODUS], 
         [VP].[PRODUCATOR], 
         [V].[ID_PUNCT_LUCRU],
         [V].[DATA_TRANZACTIE] 
     FROM 
         [SGC].[VANZARI_PRODUSE] [VP] 
     INNER JOIN
         [SGC].[VANZARI] [V] ON [VP].[ID_VANZARE] = [V].[ID_VANZARE]
     WHERE 
         ([VP].[IS_DELETED] = 0 OR [VP].[IS_DELETED] IS NULL) 
         AND VP.NUME_PRODUS IS NOT NULL 
         AND VP.PRODUCATOR IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         [V].[ID_PUNCT_LUCRU], [V].[DATA_TRANZACTIE], [VP].[NUME_PRODUS], 
         [VP].[PRODUCATOR] 
     HAVING 
         COUNT([VP].[ID_VP]) > 1) AS [VANZARI_PRODUSE_CTE] ON [VANZARI_PRODUSE_CTE].[MAX_IDVP] != [VP].[ID_VP] 
                                                           AND [VANZARI_PRODUSE_CTE].[NUME_PRODUS] = [VP].[NUME_PRODUS] 
                                                           AND [VANZARI_PRODUSE_CTE].[PRODUCATOR] = [VP].[PRODUCATOR] 
                                                           AND [VANZARI_PRODUSE_CTE].[ID_PUNCT_LUCRU] = [V].[ID_PUNCT_LUCRU] 
                                                           AND [VANZARI_PRODUSE_CTE].[DATA_TRANZACTIE] = [V].[DATA_TRANZACTIE]
```

Table `SGC.VANZARI` has an index on `ID_PUNCT_LUCRU, DATA_TRANZACTIE` and table `SGC.VANZArI_PRODUSE` has an index on `NUME_PRODUS, PRODUCATOR`.

I have one identical query that is running on a single table with all four columns, and for 33mil records completed in 7 minutes.

However the query above after 2 days and 23 hours was still running.

The temp_db database size is normal.

Any ideas, tips or tricks for improvement? Thanks

Comment: Is the query is in `Running` status ?

Comment: i stopped the query but yes, it was in running state, however after that long time no records were updated

Comment: Two tables are involved to find duplicate in one table. What is the unique combination `VANZARI_PRODUSE` table. Can we the uniqueness in `VANZARI_PRODUSE` alone to find the duplicate ? Or is it really needed to use both the tables ?

Comment: Does ssms process explorer show if it was waiting on something else?

Comment: Which of these Tables have duplicates which you want to mark deleted?

Comment: the uniqueness key must use both tables

Comment: i found the problem, it was because of the 2 indexes, i deleted them and no query runs in 8 minutes. thanks all